# softlayer API allowed ip ranges

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we use the following page to update our firewalls:
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/content/what-ip-ranges-do-i-allow-through-firewall

We have a couple of challenges with this page:
This page contains html 4 tables, which aren't easily parsed without loosing the table headers (which use span tags).
This page is unified while I'm only interested in certain subsections: Frontend (public) network, SSL VPN Datacenters & Service Network & PPTP VPN Datacenters.
The primary reason for adding this to an API, is because we don't receive updates to this page. While it could impact availability if we don't update this information on our production routers.

The CIDR ranges have been syntactically incorrect in the past. I have addressed that issue in the softlayer forum below.

**With the challenges in mind, could you provide the allowed IP ranges information in the SoftLayer API?**
The people who are responsible for providing that information are available here: https://control.softlayer.com/support/tickets/34087275

This is a closed forum, and I'll update anything relevant here. Their stance is that updating is a sysadministration problem, and therefore not their problem. They welcome API changes, and think this is the suitable forum for that.

Please note I am not looking to parse html tables, I'm looking for a solution that solves the notification problem.

Comment: You need an account to view that support ticket.

Comment: Yes Chris, that link is targeted to the developers, who should have an account.

Comment: Which doesn't help those of us who don't have (and don't want) Softlayer accounts.

Comment: The link contains all of the information I put in this ticket. I am not looking for a solution to parsing html tables, I am looking for additions to the API. So that we have accurate and up to date input for our automation scripts. If I can improve my question please let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a good information for adding to the API, I recommend to attach this forum to the ticket, in order that can reach the right people, in order to consider the implementation for it